# Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given an array of positive integers `a` I want to output array of integers `b` so that `b[i]` is the closest number to `a[i]` that is smaller then `a[i]`, and is in `{a[0], ... a[i-1]}`. If such number doesn't exist, then `b[i] = -1`.

Example:

```
a =  2  1 7 5 7 9
b = -1 -1 2 2 5 7
```

`b[0] = -1` since there is no number that is smaller than 2
`b[1] = -1` since there is no number that is smaller than 1 from `{2}`
`b[2] = 2`, closest number to 7 that is smaller than 7 from `{2,1}` is 2
`b[3] = 2`, closest number to 5 that is smaller than 5 from `{2,1,7}` is 2
`b[4] = 5`,  closest number to 7 that is smaller than 7 from `{2,1,7,5}` is 5

I was thinking about implementing balanced binary tree, however it will require a lot of work. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Would you mind working on a more-descriptive title for your question?

Comment: A 3rd array which uses the value in A[i] as its index and has a value of the "closest" number would reduce seek time as you would only need to iterate though a[i-1] until you encounter the same value in a[i] again.  Using your example I would only have to search 2 positions in A[] to find that 5>2 retain the 5 in B[] and update c[7] to now be 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a (nearly) O(n log n) algorithm that's somewhere in between the difficulty of implementing an insertion sort and balanced binary tree: Do the problem backwards, use merge/quick sort, and use binary search.

Pseudocode:

```
let c be a copy of a
let b be an array sized the same as a
sort c using an O(n log n) algorithm
for i from a.length-1 to 1
    binary search over c for key a[i] // O(log n) time
    remove the item found // Could take O(n) time
    if there exists an item to the left of that position, b[i] = that item
    otherwise, b[i] = -1
b[0] = -1
return b
```

There's a few implementation details that can make this have poor runtime.

- For instance, since you have to remove items, doing this on a regular array and shifting things around will make this algorithm still take O(n^2) time. So, you could store key-value pairs instead. One would be the key, and the other would be the number of those keys (kind of like a multiset implemented on an array). "Removing" one would just be subtracting the second item from the pair and so on.
- Eventually you will be left with a bunch of 0-value keys. This would eventually make the `if there exists an item to the left` take roughly O(n) time, and therefore, the entire algorithm would degrade to a O(n^2) for that reason. So another optimization might be to batch remove all of them periodically. For instance, when 1/2 of them are 0-values, perform a pruning.
- The ideal option might be to implement another data structure that has a much more favorable remove time. Something along the lines of a modified unrolled linked list with indices could work, but it would certainly increase the implementation complexity of this approach.

I've actually implemented this. I used the first two optimizations above (storing key-value pairs for compression, and pruning when 1/2 of them are 0s). Here's some benchmarks to compare using an insertion sort derivative to this one:

```
a.length  This method   Insert sort Method
100        0.0262ms      0.0204ms
1000       0.2300ms      0.8793ms
10000      2.7303ms     75.7155ms
100000    32.6601ms   7740.36  ms
300000    98.9956ms  69523.6   ms
1000000  333.501 ms     ????? Not patient enough
```

So, as you can see, this algorithm grows much, much slower than the insertion sort method I posted before. However, it took 73 lines of code vs 26 lines of code for the insertion sort method. So in terms of simplicity, the insertion sort method might still be the way to go if you don't have time requirements/the input is small.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```
 for i ← 1 to i ← (length(A)-1) {
     // A[i] is added in the sorted sequence A[0, .. i-1] save A[i] to make a hole at index j
     item = A[i]
     j = i

     // keep moving the hole to next smaller index until A[j - 1] is <= item
     while j > 0 and A[j - 1] > item {
         A[j] = A[j - 1]  // move hole to next smaller index
         j = j - 1
       }

     A[j] = item  // put item in the hole

     // if there are elements to the left of A[j] in sorted sequence A[0, .. i-1], then store it in b
     // TODO : run loop so that duplicate entries wont hamper results
     if j > 1
        b[i] = A[j-1]
     else 
        b[1] = -1;
   }
```

Dry run:

```
a =  2 1 7 5 7 9
a[1] = 2
```

its straight forward, set `b[1]` to -1

```
a[2] = 1
```

insert into subarray  : `[1 ,2]`
any elements before 1 in sorted array ? no.
So set `b[2]` to -1 . `b: [-1, -1]`

```
a[3] = 7
```

insert into subarray  : `[1 ,2, 7]`
any elements before 7 in sorted array ? yes. its 2
So set `b[3]` to 2.   `b: [-1, -1, 2]`

```
a[4] = 5
```

insert into subarray  : `[1 ,2, 5, 7]`
any elements before 5 in sorted array ? yes. its 2
So set `b[4]` to 2.   `b: [-1, -1, 2, 2]`

and so on..

Comment: Wouldn't the cost of re-positioning and re-dimming the array when you have a number like 2 or 5 in the above example get greater and greater as more numbers are processed?  But I like the concept; just not sure how/if that needs to be worried about.

Comment: @xQbert as numbers increase, this will not scale well. I am still thinking of ways to improve on that.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat it like an insertion sort.

Pseudocode:

```
let arr be one array with enough space for every item in a
let b be another array with, again, enough space for all elements in a
For each item in a:
    perform insertion sort on item into arr
    After performing the insertion, if there exists a number to the left, append that to b.
    Otherwise, append -1 to b
return b
```

The main thing you have to worry about is making sure that you don't make the mistake of reallocating arrays (because it would reallocate n times, which would be extremely costly). This will be an implementation detail of whatever language you use (std::vector's reserve for C++ ... arr.reserve(n) for D ... ArrayList's ensureCapacity in Java...)

A potential downfall with this approach compared to using a binary tree is that it's O(n^2) time. However, the constant factors using this method vs binary tree would make this faster for smaller sizes. If your n is smaller than 1000, this would be an appropriate solution. However, O(n log n) grows much slower than O(n^2), so if you expect a's size to be significantly higher and if there's a time limit that you are likely to breach, you might consider a more complicated O(n log n) algorithm.

There are ways to slightly improve the performance (such as using a binary insertion sort: using binary search to find the position to insert into), but generally they won't improve performance enough to matter in most cases since it's still O(n^2) time to shift elements to fit.

Comment: All that said, another approach might be available depending on your language. For instance, C++ typically (I'm not sure if it's always the case) implements multiset as a tree structure. It would be very easy to implement an O(n log n) algorithm using the C++ multiset as long as you're comfortable with iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
a =  2  1 7 5 7 9
b = -1 -1 2 2 5 7

c   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 - - - - - - - - - -
```

Where the index of C is value of a[i] such that 0,3,4,6,8 would have null values.
and the 1st dimension of C contains the highest to date closest value to a[i]

```
So in step by a[3] we have the following
    c    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
      0  - -1 -1  -  -  2  -  2  -  -

  and by step a[5] we have the following

    c    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
      0  - -1 -1  -  -  2  -  5  -  7
```

This way when we get to the 2nd 7 at a[4] we know that 2 is the largest value to date and all we need to do is loop back through a[i-1] until we encounter a 7 again comparing the a[i] value to that in c[7] if bigger, replace c[7].  Once a[i-1] = the 7 we put c[7] into b[i] and move on to next a[i].

The main downfalls to this approach that I can see are:

- footprint size depending on how big the c[] needs to be dimensioned..
- the fact that you have to revisit elements of a[] that you've already touched. If the distribution of data is such that there are significant spaces between the two 7's then keeping track of the highest value as you go would presumably be faster.  Alternatively it might be better to gather statistics on the a[i] up front to know what distributions exist and then use a hybrid method maintaining the max until such time that no more instances of that number are in the statistics.